# parsing CSV file - "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, range, index-error

I have 14 pages csv document (actually PDF but converted to csv file).
Each page has 36 lines - total lines are 544.
Between the line I need to ignore lines 325-347 & 493-507 (which is correct with - if the page has CO=  & PAGE only condition).

```
Totals Lines - 544
Page Indexes - [0, 36, 72, 108, 144, 180, 216, 252, 288, 348, 384, 420, 456, 508]
[[0, 35], [36, 71], [72, 107], [108, 143], [144, 179], [180, 215], [216, 251], [252, 287], [288, 347], [348, 383], [384, 419], [420, 455], [456, 507], [508, 544]]
```

With the code below I am getting "IndexError: list index out of range". Any help please, Thanks in Advance.

```
file = ('file name')
with open(file,'r') as fp:
    csv_reader = list(csv.reader(fp))
    num_rows = len(csv_reader)
    print("Totals Lines - " +str(num_rows))
    page_indexes = [ i for i in range(num_rows) if (('PAGE' in csv_reader[i]) and (csv_reader[i][0].strip() == 'CO='))]
    print("Page Indexes - " + str(page_indexes))
    page_nums = [ [ page_indexes[i], page_indexes[i+1]-1 ] for i in range(len(page_indexes))] 
    print(page_nums)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qza3Y.png)

Comment: can you please post your error as well? I'm guessing it's your `num_rows` variable that is causing issues.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.  In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: Your posted code dies for lack of the input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that causes the problem.
Replace your first statements with the `list` you build from the input file.

Comment: `page_indexes[i+1]` will be out of range on the last iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the last iteration of the list comprehension for `page_nums`, there's no `page_indexes[i+1]`, since `i` is the index of the last element. You need to stop before that. Then you can add the last page index separately.

```
page_nums = [ [ page_indexes[i], page_indexes[i+1]-1 ] for i in range(len(page_indexes)-1)] 
page_nums.append([page_indexes[-1], num_rows-1])
```

Comment: thanks, adding that last line worked, thank you for the help, it worked